# No medium found

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted

I received a new 2TB SATA-SSD and I attached it on my ubuntu 16.04 machine.  (I just found an empty SSD slot and connected the SATA and SATA power cable on my ASUS board). Before I attached it, I could see disks /dev/{sda,sdb,sdc,sdd,sde} but after I attached it I found new /dev/sdf there. So I guessed the new drive was assigned /dev/sdf.
But when I give `sudo gparted /dev/sdf` I get

```
ckim@chan-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo gparted /dev/sdf
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
Error opening /dev/sdf: No medium found
```

and another message window saying `Error opening /dev/sdf: No medium found` with Retry and Cancel buttons. First I tried with an SATA SSD and tried with another SATA HDD, it's the same. What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Check your motherboard manual. Sometimes SATA ports are disabled depending on the configuration of other devices. Try the new drive in a port you know is working. sdf could be a memory card slot

Comment: @PonJar yes, I vaguely thought about that kind of situation. I'll check it tomorrow when I'm at work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if I have to format the new disk first, I searched 'how to format an SSD on ubuntu' then found I can use `Disks` utility to format a disk. And volla, my new Western Digital SSD was device /dev/sdc not /dev/sdf!  I don't know how linux assigns device number.
[image]

Comment: This is not really the answer. It looks like your assumption about sdf was incorrect. I should have suggested the command lsblk. That lists all the block devices and would have shown sdc as a 2TB device. Now you have formatted a partition you will probably have sdc1 as well

Comment: yeah, maybe you're right. but I thought my "answer" can give someone a hint that he can be mistaking the device file. yes, lsblk can give the information but I remember the Disk tool gave more information about the product itself.